# supply a classpath for xmlbeans plugin

Tags: maven, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

In a *maven* project I am using *xmlbeans* plugin to generate access functions to xml schema based xml files.

*xmlbeans* needs *log4j-core* on the classpath for logging, which it misses in the *generate-sources* phase.

It issues the error

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

How can I put the regarding jar file on the classpath while *maven* is generating source code?

Here is the reduced pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.url</groupId>
    <artifactId>tstLog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>tstLog</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>eu.ngong.tstLog.App</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repackage>my.url.tstLog</repackage>
                    <name>tstLog</name>
                    <noAnn>true</noAnn>
                    <partialMethods>ALL,-GET_ARRAY,-XGET_LIST,-XGET_ARRAY</partialMethods>
                    <xmlConfigs>${basedir}/src/main/schema/tstLog.xsdconfig</xmlConfigs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```